# “The sun didn’t set” (lie) vs “John said the sun didn’t set” (not a lie)

Tags: philosophy-of-language

I didn’t know how to create a title for this question. I’m talking about how it seems possible one could understand someone saying to you “the sun didn’t set” as a lie vs internalizing as the fact “John said the sun didn’t set”. Maybe call it evaluating vs passing or wrapping. And that this possibility of doing so seems to call into question the status of truth and falsity.

The particles and fields which make up John didn’t lie when he said the sun didn’t set.

So why don’t we humans understand sentences as being “wrapped” by “so and so said __”? Instead, we just “evaluate” the sentence.

It’s certainly simpler. Is a “matter of fact” language possible where we do wrap everything?

I do worry truth and falsity may be “eliminated” if we talked this way, but if our goals changed might we begin to? Or do we know already such language is impossible in practice? Maybe we know talking in such a way wouldn’t change our understanding? But do we really know that?

Comment: For anyone curious, I happened to find this by Crispen Sartwell which at least mentions this exact concept. https://youtu.be/VK9tenA24s8?t=1509 (25:09~26:00) (he is not a deflationist though, this is one piece of a larger view)

Comment: And better to let this question die, but I think the YouTube clip may at least clear up a little of where I’m coming from, but I definitely should’ve asked a clearer question

Answer (score 2):

You are getting at a logical distinction called use-mention distinction. In the first sentence, the predicate "the sun didn't set" is used, and not only used, but asserted. The sentence is true when the truth conditions of that predicate are fulfilled. In the second sentence, the predicate "the sun didn't set" is only mentioned, not used. When a predicate is only mentioned, the truth of the predicate is not at issue.

"The sun didn't set" is a report about the apparent behavior of the sun. The subject is the sun, and the predicate is an astronomical motion. The predicate is true if the subject, "the sun" did what the predicate says it did: "didn't set".

"John said the sun didn't set" is a report about a verbal behavior of John. The subject is John (not the sun) and the predicate is a verbal performance. The predicate is true if the subject, "John", did what the predicates he did: "said the sun didn't set". What the sun did is not relevant in this predicate because the predicate about the sun is only mentioned.

Comment: Thanks David for connecting this to a real area of philosophy. But in this depiction, what does it mean for the second sentence to be true? I witnessed John say such? But that is always true. That is my sense experience. And sense experiences are facts not really truth or falsity.

Comment: @J Kusin, can your sense be wrong or mislead you? You would be the first human ever with that experience. Our sense can be wrong. How do you explain illusions? This means there are other ways to gain knowledge. Philosophers don't use the word sentences like you do. They are watering g down the concept of propositions when they use the word sentence or statement. Propositions are neither of those. Philosophers should not be using either term. The proper terminology is proposition. Propositions can be expressed by very different sentences & different languages.

Comment: @JKusin, why would you have to witness John saying it? Does the sun not set if you don't witness it? Was Lincoln not assassinated if you didn't witness it? I really don't see where that is coming from. "John said the sun didn't set" is true if and only if John said the sun didn't set, whether you witnessed him saying it or not. (I'm not asserting a disquotational view of truth here, just noting something that pretty much all philosophies of truth would agree to).

Comment: Say it’s John and me in a room and John says, “the sun didn’t set”. From that observation, I could internalize John told a lie, John told the truth, or just John said the sun didn’t set. The first two involve truth and falsity. The third is just a report of my observation. What principle is forcing these sentences or our language to be a evaluated for truth or falsity then? Maybe I just want to go around cataloguing what I observe as in the third case.

Comment: @Logikal In a certain sense our senses are never wrong though. Take the famous blue and white dress-that’s really what they saw. It seems possible language could mimic this aspect of experience: Jane said she sees blue, Alan said he sees white, the dress is measured to be 490nm wavelength and is thus blue. Alan is wrong, if he is making a claim about the world. If he is just saying what he sees, he is not wrong or right. We could speak this way if we wanted no?

Comment: @jkusin The answer would be NO without the concept of objective knowledge existing. In the moment we have no super technology to tell who is wrong right then & there. You would not know who is speaking incorrectly. Perhaps both were wrong there. We may find out much much later with an investigation. So yes right here right now one of us may make a sentence that is incorrect because one of us has vision problems no other people present are aware of the vision problems. Thus our senses cause an incorrect sentence we might not be aware of the moment it is uttered. We find out later it was false.

Comment: @JKusin, no one is forcing you to evaluate that truth or falsity of the statement. Nevertheless, assuming it expresses a proposition, then it is true or false. Similarly, if John is wearing a blue shirt no one forces you to evaluate the color of his shirt, but it is nevertheless blue. I cannot figure out what you are getting at. All of this seems quite trivial.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Well maybe in some cases the raw utterances are more valuable than whether they are true or not. Im trying to figure that out. For one reason it is a way for language to mirror the realness of experience. Another we could hold off on forming any ontological commitments.

Comment: @Logikal I guess if one thought we wouldn’t have the right ontology for 1 million years, maybe it’d be more useful just to catalog people’s utterances for future thinkers to learn about. And that language should be primarily used for sharing our raw experiences for the better future thinkers. If one studies Frege’s predicate language, presumably one thinks it’s useful or true. Maybe under this future it’s wasted effort. What sub field  talks about how we intentionally use language?

Comment: @j justin, one field is epistemology which already has the field of semantics inside;  then there is just the pure field of linguistics that discusses how language works on multiple levels. Semantics is in philosophy though because  philosophy cares about true propositions --not sentences. Sentences are not propositions nor vice versa. We can express the same proposition in different sentences in the same language like English. We can also Express the same proposition in a completely different language with sentences. Either way propositions are valued true or false. Grammar is different.